# Dockerでlocalhostでの接続が上手くできなくて困っております。

Tags: docker, apache

解決したいこと

独学エンジニアという山浦さんの教材を用いて勉強しているのですが、HTML→apache→ブラウザ(ここが表示されない)
詳細はお手数ですが下記のTwitterを見て頂きたく思います。
https://twitter.com/derasado/status/1366361339925434369

詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、幸いです。

・ブラウザに表示されない問題を解消したいです。

発生している問題・エラー
エラー内容：このサイトにアクセスできません
localhost で接続が拒否されました。

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "50080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.5.62
    ports:
      - "53306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - ./docker/db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./docker/db/db-variables.env
```

**docker/app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# PHP で必要なライブラリをインストール
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libonig-dev libzip-dev unzip mariadb-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring zip

# composer のインストール
COPY --from=composer:1.10 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

# ファイルのコピー
COPY ./src /var/www/html
COPY ./docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```